# How to insert a variable into an "input" function

Tags: python, function, variables, syntax

I want show two variables in a prompt line in Python as this:

```
a = 35
b = 11
captcha = int(input(a, '+', b '='))
```

It must looks like:
35 + 11 =

The terminal say there is a SyntaxError. Can someone fix my syntax please? Thanks!

Comment: your missing the third comma after the second `b`. `(a, '+', a, '=')). Also `input` takes one argument. `,` separates arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two problems.

You miss the third comma to separate `b` and `=`.
Then input takes only one argument. If you try and concatenate strings in a function, python will think you are trying to add multiple arguments. Try using `f-strings` instead.

```
captcha = int(input(f'{a} + {b} ='))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an f string:

```
captcha =  int(input(f'{a} + {b} = '))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. In this situation, I suggest explaining why the OP's technique does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simpler way to do what you are trying to do:
`captcha = int(input(f"{a}+{b}="))`